# is this an issue with my monitor , or is it just in windows 10 settings?

Tags: windows-10, display, desktop-computer, display-settings

[image]

basically it is and horizontal line shadow-like and it appears better in black screen but it is everywhere.

Comment: I can't see anything in the marked areas. If it shows up on photos but not screenshots, that makes it a monitor problem.

Comment: I don’t see anything. Is you monitor hooked up using a VGA cable (blue ends usually)? This could be an artifact from an analog signal that using a digital cable would solve. I.e. HDMI or DVI. It could also be a bad monitor or video card.